# Recolor links in a page if the URL is contained in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to recolor all the links within `obj` array in a page if they match the number in `procura`.

So, `obj = [6849,6850]`

And `procura` is defined below:

```
function getLastNumberOfString(str){
  var allNumbers = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ' ').trim().split(/\s+/);
  return parseInt(allNumbers[allNumbers.length - 1], 10);
}

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a.mod-articles-category-title').each(function () {
    var $link=jQuery(this);
    var href=$link.attr('href'); 
    var procura = getLastNumberOfString(href)

    jQuery.each(obj,function(_,test) {
      if(test.indexOf(procura)!=-1) { // only works on strings 
        jQuery(this).css({'color':'#45AAA2'});
        jQuery(this).delay(1000);
        jQuery(this).animate({
        color:"#CCCCCC"
        },3000);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is returning the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'color' in undefined`

I think it is because `this` is not correctly defined, but how to fix it?

Comment: If you need to animate colour, please include `jQuery.UI.js`.

Comment: Thanks, it is already included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the nested `each()` method, `this` refers to each element of the array.  Instead, you want it to refer to each anchor in the jQuery collection returned by the outermost `each()`.

Store the current anchor in a variable for use in the nested `each()` method.  You've already created that variable, named `$link`:

```
$(function() {
  $('a.mod-articles-category-title').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    var href = $link.attr('href');
    var procura = getLastNumberOfString(href);

    $.each(obj, function(_, test) {
      if (test.indexOf(procura) != -1) { // only works on strings 
        $link.css({
          'color': '#45AAA2'
        });
        $linkdelay(1000);

        $link.animate({
          color: "#CCCCCC"
        }, 3000);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I just found it. Lol, the variable $link is already doing it!

Comment: Ha, yes, you can use that instead of `$self`!  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the links, you'd want to check out the [jQuery [attribute*=value] Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_contains_string_value.asp). It allows you to select all links with an attribute containing a certain string. You'd be able to just write a loop to build selectors that look like this `$("[href*='6849']")`

```
obj = [6849,6850]
obj.forEach(function(code){
   var selector = "[href*='" + code + "']";
   $(selector).css({'color':'#45AAA2'});
   ... etc
})
```